# Why am I getting infinity as the output? Can you find the mistake in the program?

Tags: c, arrays

The problem is to input 10 points (x,y). The program should find the distance between the consecutive points and give the output as the 'sum of the distances' OR the distance between the first and last point. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Terminal.

RUN OF THE PROGRAM

Input

```
(Enter the coordinates of the 10 points.)
1.000000 2.000000 
3.000000 4.000000 
5.000000 6.000000 
7.000000 8.000000 
9.000000 10.000000 
11.000000 12.000000 
1.000000 13.000000 
14.000000 15.000000 
16.000000 17.000000 
18.000000 19.000000
```

Output

```
Entered points:
1.000000 2.000000 
3.000000 4.000000 
5.000000 6.000000 
7.000000 8.000000 
9.000000 10.000000 
11.000000 12.000000 
1.000000 13.000000 
14.000000 15.000000 
16.000000 17.000000 
18.000000 19.000000 

Distance between first and last point is: inf.
```

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    double points[10][2],dist = 0;
    printf("Enter the coordinates of the 10 points.\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&points[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Entered points:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%f ",points[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        dist = dist + sqrt(pow((points[i][0]-points[i+1][0]),2)+pow((points[i][1]-points[i+1][1]),2));        
    }
    printf("Distance between first and last point is: %f.\n",dist);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: well, did you try using a debugger?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `code.tio.c:28:57: warning: iteration 9 invokes undefined behavior` - so says `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O2`.

Comment: @OznOg Did you give the same input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [third] `for` loop is iterating past the end of your array and you are fetching garbage/undefined data.

In your calculation loop, you are using (e.g.) `points[i+1][0]`. On the last iteration, `i` will be `9`, so `i+1` will be 10. This is one past the end.

Reduce the number of loops to 9. You are comparing *pairs* of points, so you need to reduce the count.

Answer (score 0):

When i becomes 9, points[i+1] is undefined.

Try below fix:

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("ivalue:%d\n", i);
        dist = dist + sqrt(pow((points[i][0]-points[i+1]    [0]),2)+pow((points[i][1]-points[i+1][1]),2));        
    }
```

It will output:
Distance between first and last point is: 43.001812.